# how to margin text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have 2 row text and its going like this.

[image]

this is the code.

```
Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 150.0,
                                child: Text(
                                  "Agent Ship and Bunker",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                      color: Colors.black87,
                                      fontFamily: "Sans",
                                      // fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontSize:
                                          mediaQuery.devicePixelRatio +
                                              12.0),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  "100000 USD",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontFamily: "Sans",
                                      // fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontSize:
                                          mediaQuery.devicePixelRatio +
                                              9.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
```

and how to make text align with the top parallel like this? :/

[image]

thank you... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do so, you must wrap your first `Text` into `Expanded` and the Widget `Row` must have the property `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start. Try this :

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text("Agent Ship and Bunker", style: TextStyle(
        letterSpacing: 0.5,
        color: Colors.black87,
        fontFamily: "Sans",
        // fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: mediaQuery.devicePixelRatio + 12.0,), 
        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
      child: Text(
        "100000 USD",
        style: TextStyle(
            letterSpacing: 0.5,
            color: Colors.black54,
            fontFamily: "Sans",
            // fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontSize:
            mediaQuery.devicePixelRatio +
                9.0),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```